# How does the delete queue work/is this a bug

Tags: support

Recently [this question about psychology and personal motivation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/416226/my-sister-absolutely-refuses-to-learn-math) came up in the [delete queue](https://math.stackexchange.com/tools). When I came across it yesterday it had 2 delete votes, and I added my own which put it at the top of the delete queue. However, today when I went in to continue help clear the clutter, it was no longer present. Out of curiosity, I searched for the question and found it still exists, but is no longer high up in the "most votes" queue, indeed (at least for me) it is not even visible in the list of questions with the most delete votes, despite having more than any of the others I **can** see at a given time.

**Why I think this is a bug**

The question linked was very popular in terms of votes (as is not uncommon of similar styled questions), it was closed as off-topic only after accruing many votes for whatever reason. My understanding of the way the queuing system on MSE works is more votes/answers with votes the more confirmations the system requests for deletion, with most ordinary ones requiring only 3. Because most ordinary questions disappear after those 3 delete votes, almost never is there a question in the queue with more than 2 standing votes, waiting for more to complete it, and in this case that question obtained the de-facto most of any standing vote-count, and so was put at the top of the "most votes" list and should theoretically remain there until it reaches the threshhold. The queue seemed, at the time, to sort by number of current, valid delete votes from 10k+ users, but has since disappeared from that same list when I try to view it.

I'm not certain if the site simply decides on a new batch after a day of MSE time passes or if this is a bug. If it is the latter how can we go about getting it addressed? Especially for pop-math questions which are far too broad for even the educators on our site, it requires many delete votes to clear out questions such as the example and [we already seem to have issues](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16255/how-to-repair-the-close-delete-pipeline) efficiently deleting them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see this question at the top of "most votes" column on the delete page (with 30 day period selected). It's not among "recent votes" anymore as there are more recent ones. The total number of posts displayed in each column is limited.

So, it appears there is no bug... just a fairly unintuitive interface.

Comment: Mine does not show up on the "most votes" part of the queue, sorry if that was unclear, I'll edit the original post to be more clear.

Comment: Oh perfect, thanks. It works now and I was just not knowing what to look for.

Answer (score 2):

The "most votes" refers not to the global number of votes but to the number of votes during a certain period of time, and this period of time  is selectable at the top right from (30d|14d|7d|2d|today).

At the point of writing this the specific question is not yet anymore in the list of ['most votes today'](https://math.stackexchange.com/tools?tab=Delete&daterange=today) yet it still is in all other lists, such as ['most votes, last 30 days'](https://math.stackexchange.com/tools?tab=Delete&daterange=last30days) and should staty in that last list for still almost 30 days. (Note: the links are 10k+ only, sorry.)

To me this design makes sense. If a question does not manage to get the required votes within 30 days I think it can be dropped from display. I would agree that a single day would be too short, but as explained there is the option to select different periods of time, and I hope this information resolves the issue.